# Create Tuple from Dictionary Values

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I create a tuple using Tuple.Create from dictionary values?

I have a dictionary:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> dNameProps = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Then I have added values:

```
internal static void InitializeVals()
{
    foreach(var items in lstOfNames)
    var name = item.name + " " + item.item1.ToString(); 
    var prop = item.properties;
    dNameProps.Add(name, prop);
}
```

I need to create a tuple from these values where the name is equal to a key in the dictionary

Here is what I have so far:

```
private static void GetParametersImplementation(string name , params object[] args)
{
    var Nname = name ;
    if (args.Any())
    {
        //string nameX =dNameProps[name]
        var perProperties = Tuple.Create("", args[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your second function have to do with the first? I don't see any dictionary in there.

Comment: I am trying to get the values of the dictionary using name as key.

Comment: Why "values" plural ? only one value is associated to a key in a dict and keys are unique. Question as is is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Array of tuples:

```
var result = dNameProps.Select(o => Tuple.Create(o.Key, o.Value)).ToArray();
```

Comment: @VennaMichiki can you accept my answer or should I improve it?

Answer (score -1):

```
Tuple<string, string>[] lstTuple = 
        dNameProps.Select(kvp => new Tuple<string, string>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)).ToArray();
```